# iOS DDMathParser Get Number 'Blocks'

Tags: ios, nsstring, numbers, expression, calculator

I am building a calculator app for iOS using DDMathParser. **I would like to know how to separate an expression (`NSString`) like `5+900/32` into its individual number values: `5`, `900`, and `32`.** I would prefer that I get these in an `NSArray` or other relatively useful list object. I have heard that there is an easy way to do this with `DDMathParser` - It's why I switched from `GCMathParser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDMathParser author here.

Yes, this is very easy, and there are a couple of ways to go about it.  If you simply want what the numbers are and don't care about the operators, you can use the [tokenizing](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Tokenizing) API:

```
NSError *tokenizingError = nil;
DDMathStringTokenizer *tokenizer = [DDMathStringTokenizer tokenizerWithString:@"5+900/32" error:&tokenizingError];
NSArray *tokens = [tokenizer tokens];

NSMutableArray *numbers = [NSMutableArray array];
for (DDMathStringToken *token in tokens) {
  if ([token tokenType] == DDTokenTypeNumber) {
    [numbers addObject:[token numberValue]];
  }
}

// numbers now is @[ @5, @900, @32 ];
```

There is, however, a caveat to this approach, and it can be best illustrated with this example:  `@"-42"`.  Tokens in DDMathParser are always parsed as *unsigned* numbers, because the minus sign in front is actually an operator and gets applied differently depending on other operators.  That means that if you tokenize the string `@"-42"`, you'll see that it contains *two* tokens: a negation operator, and the number 42.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Nice that the author would answer this!