# DDMathParser - Getting tokens

Tags: objective-c, ddmathparser

I'm looking to get tokens back from a string (to aid in editing) and referring to the answer here [iOS DDMathParser Get Number 'Blocks'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417462/ios-ddmathparser-get-number-blocks) it appears that this functionality may be deprecated. What is the most up-to-date way to get token objects from my string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So, this appears to be the current way of getting tokens from a string:

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    DDMathOperatorSet *opSet = [DDMathOperatorSet defaultOperatorSet];
    DDMathStringTokenizer *tokenizer = [[DDMathStringTokenizer alloc] initWithString:@"123+142-3/51815*(-5+2.0)" operatorSet:opSet error:&error];
    NSArray *tokens = [tokenizer allObjects];
```