# Getting DDMathParser tokens and group tokens

Tags: swift, ddmathparser

I already found a solution to my problem on stackoverflow but it is in Objective-C. See this link
[DDMathParser - Getting tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30741923/ddmathparser-getting-tokens)

I translated this into Swift as shown below. So what is the latest way to get tokens from a string and to get grouped tokens?

For example: 1 + ($a - (3 / 4))

Here is my try:

```
do{
    let token = try Tokenizer(string: "1 + ($a - (3 /4))").tokenize()
    for element in token {
        print(element)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

But I get the following messages:

```
MathParser.DecimalNumberToken
MathParser.OperatorToken
MathParser.OperatorToken
MathParser.VariableToken
MathParser.OperatorToken
MathParser.OperatorToken
MathParser.DecimalNumberToken
MathParser.OperatorToken
MathParser.DecimalNumberToken
MathParser.OperatorToken
MathParser.OperatorToken
```

How do I get the specific tokens from my string?

Comment: Could u look at my code and tell me what I am missing, please ?

Comment: *How do I get the specific tokens from my string ?* You are iterating over the tokens, so you have them already.

Comment: What do you mean by "grouped" tokens?

Comment: @DaveDeLong What i mean by "grouped" tokens are the group terms. Here in my example we would have 3 group terms. My question is how do I get the group terms ?

Comment: @TBH in that case, I think you may just want the final `Expression` tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting all of the tokens.

`OperatorToken`, `DecimalNumberToken`, etc all inherit from a `RawToken` superclass. `RawToken` defines a `.string` and a `.range` property.

The `.string` is the actual `String`, as extracted or inferred from the source. The `.range` is where in the original string the token is located.

It's important to note, however, that there may be tokens produced by the tokenizer that are not present in the original string. For example, tokens get injected by the Tokenizer when resolving implicit multiplication (`3x` turns in to `3 * x`).

---

Added later:

If you want the *final* tree of how it all gets parsed, then you want the `Expression`:

```
let expression = try Expression(string: "1 + ($a - (3 / 4))")
```

At this point, you `switch` on `expression.kind`. It'll either be a `number`, a `variable`, or a `function`. `function` expressions have child expressions, representing the arguments to the function.

Comment: If I have the following expression "let expression = try Expression(string: "1 - ($a - (3/4)) + ($a + 2)"), I get the message
"function("add", [1.0 - $a - 3.0 / 4.0 + $a, 2.0])". My question: How do I know that $a-3/4 is in brackets ?

Comment: @TBH that looks like the `description`. As I mentioned, you'll want to `switch` on the `expression.kind`. That'll tell you it's a `.function` expression, and you'll get the 2 arguments as part of the enum payload. The two arguments will both be expressions: the first will be `.number(1.0)`, and the second will be what you're looking for